# Strip HTML from a string in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, meta-tags, createelement

I'd like a to populate my meta description with a field 'summary' which is stored as HTML.
The field often contains links when used as a blog listing summary so has to be stored as HTML so I need a way to grab the text when using it in meta tags.

So in Nuxt.js with SSG/SSR I can't use `document.createElement`,
I don't want to force the author to manage two fields for the same content, and the 'browser only' workarounds like `if(process.client)` don't apply here as this needs to be server-side content.

I'm currently using a regex like `this.blog.summary.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")`
But this feels like it that will be unreliable

Is there a better more Nuxt.js + SSR/SSG way to extract text from  HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-strip-html and it worked fine in SSR.

But the actual version is a little unstable actually I am using version ^8.3.0.